# We should go [about/on/to]…

Tags: word-choice, phrasal-verbs

> We should go **about/on/to** doing more good than harm.

**Go about** is a phrasal verb which says **to deal with something**. How should I go **about** telling her truth.
**Go on** says which continues.
**Go to** somewhere.

So, out of the three options I find **go on** as the best. However, none of them suits the best. But the answer of this question is **go about**.

Comment: Where exactly is this "answer" given? Textbook? Sometimes, the books are incorrect. Verify with a valid source.

Comment: They mean different things:  "To go about doing something" here means in general, everywhere you go you should try to do more good than harm. It's a rule to live by.   "To go on doing more good than harm" implies that you have already been doing more good than harm and that we should continue to do so.  "to go to doing more good than harm" uses more informal language where "go to" here means "move to a mode where we are" In other words, "We should switch our behavior so that we are doing more good than harm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to The Free Dictionary, the phrasal verb **go about** also means to *actively and constantly be engaged in doing something* such as "He went about doing good".  I think, in light of this definition, the phrase fits well in the sentence presented.

However, it's not incorrect if you use the phrase "go on" in the sentence, which means to keep on doing something.

Answer (score 0):

> We should go *about/on/to* doing more good than harm.

The phrase has nothing to do with going somewhere, so you can't use *go on*.

To consider *go about*, try some substitution. Using your definition:

> We should **deal with** doing more good than harm.

where "doing more good than harm" is *something*. Not the best definition but it basically makes sense.